# Manage tabbed content with full support for routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, tabs

I'm building an `Asp.net mvc 3` application. What I want to do, is a profile page (*pretty mutch like the stackoverflow profile page*), and the content of this page will be splited in tabs, each tab is represented by an `PartialView`.

When the user click on the tab X, I want to refresh only the tab area, without refreshing all my page. And in the same time changing my URL adress, so if the user click on the browser refresh button, it refresh the page with the selected tab. Is this possible ?

What I already know, is how to get data using `AJAX`, and replace the content of my view. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978025/how-can-i-build-a-tabbed-menu-in-asp-net-mvc) , I found it interesting, but it refresh all the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to take (any existing) asp.net mvc "control" that does this, and prefer to create your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You will need to use both ajax to get the html to render without refreshing the page, as well as use push state to update the URL to include the current tab.

You could do these things as separate operations, but I would suggest using [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/). With PJAX you will need a little additional logic in your server to decide whether to return the full html page with the layout, or just return the partial (a PJAX request).

Here is our Foo controller. Index has a default selected tab of "Bar". The Bar and Baz actions return the Index view, but with different tabs being the selected tab. If it is a PJAX request, then all we need is the partial view that fills in the tab content.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedTab = "Bar";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        if(Request.Headers["X-PJAX"] != null)
            return PartialView();
        ViewBag.SelectedTab = "Bar";
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Baz()
    {
        if (Request.Headers["X-PJAX"] != null)
            return PartialView();
        ViewBag.SelectedTab = "Baz";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Inside of the Foo/Index.cshtml we have the Razor code that will determine what partial view to render based on `ViewBag.SelectedTab`.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Foo";
}

<h2>Foo</h2>

<ul>
    <li><a class="tabs" href="@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo")">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a class="tabs" href="@Url.Action("Baz", "Foo")">Baz</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab_content">
    @if(ViewBag.SelectedTab == "Bar")
    {
        @Html.Partial("Bar")
    }
    @if (ViewBag.SelectedTab == "Baz")
    {
        @Html.Partial("Baz")
    }
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".tabs").pjax("#tab_content");
        })
    </script>
}
```

The script section at the end is how you wire up PJAX. You are telling it, for all hyperlinks with the `tabs` class use pjax to dynamically load and render the html resulting from the `href` into the container with the id `tab_content` and update the url in the browser to be the url from the `href`.

Each tab's partial view is fairly simple in this scenario

Bar.cshtml

```html
<p>This is the Bar tab. No pun intended.</p>
```

Baz.cshtml

```html
<p>This is the baz tab.</p>
```

This is obviously a very simplified solution. You typically would want to use a presentation model to handle the logic of the view. Also, I have intentionally left out any tab styling to demonstrate that this technique can be used on any type of link. It is not limited to only tabs.

The [full source code](https://github.com/kmcginnes/PjaxTabs) for this example can be on my GitHub site.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It seams that you solution on GitHub was generated by VS 2012, so I wasn't able to open it. but your post here provides me suffisant informations on how to do it. It works fine ;)

Comment: If you install .net 4.5 and asp.net mvc 4 then it should open fine in VS 2010. Regardless, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user click on the tab X, I want to refresh only the tab area, without refreshing all my page. And in the same time changing my URL adress, so if the user click on the browser refresh button, it refresh the page with the selected tab. Is this possible ?

To accomplish this you need to plug into browser's history API (and it's part of HTML5, and you'll have to use some kind of plugin to get the same thing in browsers that does not support it).

Manning's "HTML5 for .net developers" has pretty good section on that, but it's still in "early access".